# dynamic value in parent node in json from c# linq

Tags: c#, json, linq

I need to set the value of the parent node dynamically
I am using LINQ to obtain result in the data table
can you please help?

Datatable data.

```
    +-----------------+----------------------------------------+-----------+
    |       Key       |                 Value                  | filetype  |
    +-----------------+----------------------------------------+-----------+
    | Sorry           | UNDSKYLD!                              | Associate |
    | ValSpace        | Mellemrum er ikke tilladt              | Associate |
    | UpdtProfile_Sub | Актуализация на потребителски профил   | Emails    |
    | UplineMail_msg  | Моля, потвърдете Нивото на потребителя | Emails    |
    +-----------------+----------------------------------------+-----------+
```

what I have tried.

```
        DataTable dt = fillDataTable();

        var result = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                     group row by row.Field<string>("filetype") into Group
                     let row = Group.First()
                     select new
                     {
                         filetype = Group.Select(row => new clsTranslation
                         {
                             Key = row.Field<string>(0),
                             Value = row.Field<string>(1),
                         }).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
                     };

        string newjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

received result.

```
          {
            "filetype": {
              "Sorry": "UNDSKYLD! ",
              "ValSpace": "Mellemrum er ikke tilladt  ",
          },
              "filetype": {
              "UpdtProfile_Sub": "Актуализация на потребителски профил ",
              "UplineMail_msg": "Моля, потвърдете Нивото на потребителя",
          }

        }
```

expected result.

```
          {
            "Associate": {
              "Sorry": "UNDSKYLD! ",
              "ValSpace": "Mellemrum er ikke tilladt  ",
          },
              "Emails": {
              "UpdtProfile_Sub": "Актуализация на потребителски профил ",
              "UplineMail_msg": "Моля, потвърдете Нивото на потребителя",
          }

        }
```

Comment: `select new` is creating an anonymous type with a property called `filetype`. If this isn't what you wanted, perhaps you need to create a dictionary of filetype<->value?

Comment: can you please help me to achive this

Comment: Make an object in C# that has the same structure as the JSON you want to produce.

Answer (score 0):

there are two approaches.

1. more generic JSON
2. as you requested

```
var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("Key"), new DataColumn("Value"), new DataColumn("filetype") });
    dt.Rows.Add("Sorry", "UNDSKYLD!", "Associate");
    dt.Rows.Add("ValSpace", "Mellemrum er ikke tilladt", "Associate");
    dt.Rows.Add("UpdtProfile_Sub", "Актуализация на потребителски профил", "Emails");
    dt.Rows.Add("UplineMail_msg", "Моля, потвърдете Нивото на потребителя", "Emails");
```

Generic approach

```
    var rez = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(gp => gp.Field<string>("filetype")).ToList()
                .Select(fe => new
                {
                    Type = fe.Key,
                    Data = fe.ToList().Select(ss => (ss.Field<string>("Key").ToString(), ss.Field<string>("Value")))
                });
                   //would be generic
    Console.Writeline(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rez, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
```

ANOTHER APPROACH as you requested

```
    JArray jArray = new JArray();
    dt.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(gp => gp.Field<string>("filetype")).ToList()
        .ForEach(fe =>
        {
            var jo = new JObject();
            var test = JObject.FromObject(jo);
            fe.ToList().ForEach(e =>
            {
                test.Add(e.Field<string>("Key"), e.Field<string>("Value"));
            });
            jo.Add(fe.Key, test);
            jArray.Add(jo);
        });
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jArray, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
```

first approach result:

```
[
  {
    "Type": "Associate",
    "Data": [
      {
        "Item1": "Sorry",
        "Item2": "UNDSKYLD!"
      },
      {
        "Item1": "ValSpace",
        "Item2": "Mellemrum er ikke tilladt"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Type": "Emails",
    "Data": [
      {
        "Item1": "UpdtProfile_Sub",
        "Item2": "Актуализация на потребителски профил"
      },
      {
        "Item1": "UplineMail_msg",
        "Item2": "Моля, потвърдете Нивото на потребителя"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

second approach result:
[image]

```
[
  {
    "Associate": {
      "Sorry": "UNDSKYLD!",
      "ValSpace": "Mellemrum er ikke tilladt"
    }
  },
  {
    "Emails": {
      "UpdtProfile_Sub": "Актуализация на потребителски профил",
      "UplineMail_msg": "Моля, потвърдете Нивото на потребителя"
    }
  }
]
```